# When using :before on an element it becomes the first child of said element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, css-content

I've always used :before in CSS to mean put content *before* the selector. I've never had any problems with this, however, I've stumbled across something that is confusing me where a selector's :before is appending *inside* the element instead of coming *before* it. I don't see why this is the case.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vMtct/1/

And here is the basic code:

```
<div class="block">
  <p>But this &lt;p&gt; will have content <em>before</em>.</p>
</div>
```

```css
.block {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 50px; }
.block:before {
  background: #eeeeee;
  content: "Here is something that print's inside the selector";
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px; }
p:before {
  display: block;
  content: ">>>"; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:before` and `:after` are pseudo elements, that are not actually added to the DOM. They are inserted before *the content* of the element.

It is also therefore that they don't work on 'empty' (self closing) elements like `<input />` or `<img/>`.

You could however get these pseudo elements to display 'outside' the element they are applied on, by positioning them absolute as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/vMtct/2/

Comment: Ok. I get what you're saying. So basically you're saying in theory the examples I've given would look like <div>"before content" content</div> which is why it's inside the box and <p>"before content" content</p> which is why it appears actually before. Got it. I guess adding some styles to <p> could have shown that.

Comment: I think I've only ever used :before on inline elements like that and so that was what was causing the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements work on empty elements, too; e.g., CSS 2.1 has a rule with `br:after` in its default style sheet for HTML 4.01. For some empty elements (replaced elements), there can be limitations. But basically, for an empty element, these pseudo-elements cause content to be inserted right before or right after its content proper (which just happens to be empty).

Comment: When using before and after and you use js append, does the js know about the before or after? I ask becasue the CSS is loaded first...

Comment: as far as I know, js can only access the DOM, so no pseudo elements. Also js applies styling directly to the element (style attribute) and it is not possible to add a pseudo element inside the style attribute. My guess would be **no**, unless somebody can prove me wrong...

Comment: You can add styles inside <style>, http://jsfiddle.net/cCgxJ/ You just have to write your append for the $style instead of the element itself. This one appends the style tage along with the psuedo element as I don't think jsfiddle has a style tag to append to but if you set up a simple test you can see it.